# Como disparar o scroll usando javascript puro?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como implementar no javascript puro a mesma ação utilizada com jQuery abaixo:

```
$('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: 500
}, 300);
```

Alguém sabe me dizer como ficaria o código?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usando `window.scroll`, assim:

```
window.scroll({top: 500, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })
```

```css
p {height: 40px; vertical-align: middel; border: solid 1px}
```

```html
<h1>Rolar o html até o final...</h1>
<p>.....</p>
<p>.....</p>
<p>.....</p>
<p>.....</p>
<p>.....</p>
<p>.....</p>
<p>.....</p>
<p>.....</p>
<p>para encher a página...</p>
<p>.....</p>
<p>.....</p>
<p>.....</p>
<p>.....</p>
<p>.....</p>
<p>.....</p>
<p>.....</p>

<input type='button' onclick="window.scroll({top: 500, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })" value="clique aqui para executar o scroll" />
```

Para complementar, esse recurso chama-se *"Smooth Scrolling"*, e é documentado no W3C: https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#smooth-scrolling

Comment: Muito obrigado @Ricardo

Comment: Eu procurei na documentação https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll e não encontrei esses parâmetros ai. Mas isso resolveu meu problema. Tem algum link que você poderia me passar que mostra a documentação do window.scroll?

Comment: Use `window.scrollTo` porque o `window.scroll` ficou obsoleto.

Comment: @MiguelBatista adicionei na resposta a referência do W3C, e tem esse ótimo link em inglês também: https://hospodarets.com/native_smooth_scrolling

Comment: verdade @dvd bem pontuado